# How do you derive the day of week in Foundry Contour?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

I want to derive a column for day of week for a time value. There are `DAY_OF_MONTH` and `DAY_OF_YEAR` functions in Contour, but not one for day of week.

How can I derive the day of the week using Contour?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no `DAY_OF_WEEK` function, but you can use this workaround:

```
date_format("<NameOfYourDateColumn>", 'EEE')
```